# possible speed up of pandas apply

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, cython

I defined two functions which will be used in my program over and over again:

The first function is to turn string into datetime, and the second function is to read a csv file and extract one value right before an event happened and one value right after the event and return the rest data frame after the event.

```
def to_timestamp(timestr):
   return datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr,'%H:%M:%S.%f')
def find_values(df,ticker,event_time):
   df=pd.read_csv(ticker+'.csv',sep=',')
   df['Time'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(to_timestamp)
   df_earlier = df[df['Time']<=newstime]
   df_later = df[df['Time']>newstime]
   price_1=df_earlier['Price'].iloc[-1]
   price_2=df_later['Price'].iloc[0]
   return (price_1,Price_2,df_later)
```

The csv file has the following form:

```
     Timestamp,       Price 
   04:15:01.274, 35.50
   04:15:01.353, 35.71
   04:15:05.184, 37.37
   05:36:25.240, 37.60
   05:44:40.678, 36.51
   …
```

Both functions works, but they are very slow if I use them on thousands of csv files. I think the main bottleneck is the apply method. Is there anyway to speed it up? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def find_values(ticker, event_time):
    filename = ticker+'.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[0])
    idx = df['Timestamp'].searchsorted(event_time, side='right')
    price_1, price_2 = df['Price'].iloc[idx-1:idx+1]
    df_later = df.iloc[idx:]
    return price_1, price_2, df_later
```

---

For example, using the data you posted:

```
In [176]: p1, p2, df_later = find_values('ABC', pd.Timestamp('4:15:03'))

In [177]: p1, p2
Out[177]: (35.710000000000001, 37.369999999999997)

In [178]: df_later
Out[178]: 
                   Timestamp  Price
2 2015-01-19 04:15:05.184000  37.37
3 2015-01-19 05:36:25.240000  37.60
4 2015-01-19 05:44:40.678000  36.51
```

---

Parsing a csv can be expensive if the csv is large. Therefore, you do not want
to call `pd.read_csv` more than once if you can help it. By extension, you
should not call `find_values` more than once for each ticker. If you do need to
call `find_values` more than once for the same ticker, thought needs to be put
into how the algorithm can be reworked so ideally `pd.read_csv` can be called
only once. Caching the value returned by `pd.read_csv` might be one way, or
collecting the `event_times` into one call to `find_values` might be another
way.

Now assuming you are already calling `find_values` parsimoniously, let's move on to how we can improve it's speed.

You are right that using `apply` here is also a potential bottleneck, since it is calling a Python function once for each row of the dataframe. Instead of parsing the time strings using `to_timestamp`, you could instead use `pd.read_csv`'s  built-in date string parsing ability:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[0])
```

This will parse the 0-th indexed column as a date string. This will make
`df['Timestamp']` a column with dtype `datetime64[ns]`.
That's terrific, since it makes finding the index where `event_time` (which I assume is the same thing as `newstime`) fits into `df['Timestamp']` very easy. Moreover, date calculations can in general be performed much faster on datetime64s than equivalent calculations done on Python `datetime.datetime` objects.

To find the integer index where `event_time` would fit use [the `searchsorted` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html):

```
idx = df['Timestamp'].searchsorted(event_time)
```

`idx` will be the integer index where `event_time` would go if it were to be inserted into `df['Timestamp']` while maintaining `df['Timestamp']`'s sortedness.

---

Next, note that using

```
df_earlier = df[df['Time']<=newstime]
```

is also expensive because it forms a (potentially large) dataframe just to pick off one value. Since `df['Time']<=newstime` is a boolean mask, this new dataframe `df[df['Time']<=newstime]` makes a *copy* of data from `df`. That's a lot of unnecessary copying.

Instead, you could use

```
price_1, price_2 = df['Price'].iloc[idx-1:idx+1]
```

to pick off just the values you want without a lot of extra copying.

Finally, you could use

```
df_later = df.iloc[idx:]
```

to define `df_later`. Since this uses basic slicing instead of a boolean mask, `df_later` *is a view* of `df`.  This is faster to generate than `df[df['Time']>event_time]` because there is no copying. But also beware that this means the underlying data in `df_later` is the very same data underlying `df`. As a consequence, modifying `df_later` also modifies `df` and vice versa. If you do not want `df_later` to be a view, then use

```
df_later = df.iloc[idx:].copy()
```

Comment: Never used searchsorted before, thank you very much!

Comment: I finally understand the difference between mask and slicing! Thank you!